# OTP verification in Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-android

How to read OTP SMS on an android device when doing a login test to another app?

I am currently pausing the test and entering the OTP manually and running the test. But I want to automate it.

There are some methods to read an SMS body but I don't know how to open the messaging app and read the body while running another app.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Appium and Selenium can easily run the JavaScript commands, so the easiest way is:

```
sms_inbox = driver.execute_script("mobile: listSms")
sms_list = sms_inbox['items']
```